# Glass jar becomes black in cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glass

[image: This is the shader nodes]Im quite new to blender and i was wondering why my glass jar becomes black in cycles render.Here is the photo[image: This is the eevie render]

[image: Here is the cycles render]

The first photo is on eevie render while the second photo is on cycles render

Comment: hello, could you please share one of the objects? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I upload the project file because i dont know how to share one of the objects.Is it ok?

Comment: Hi and welcome :) Please [edit] your question and add an image showing your shader nodes.

Comment: Timaroberts,up there is the shader nodes,Thanks

Comment: Use a glass shader instead of the principled shader.